# CHALLENGE: Prove that a product of two summable sequences is summable

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that a "product" of two summable sequences is summable.

(notice the sequence does not necessarily have to be non-negative)

Comment: it's easy, what did you try? Do $N-\delta$ definition. (Usually at MSE you are expected to describe what you tried, and where you have difficulties.)

Comment: There is less to this than meets the eye. The solution follows directly from the definition of the sum of a series.

Comment: Say the $A$ series converges to $a$ (that is, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty A(n)=a$ and the $B$ series converges to $b$. Given any $\delta>0$ there is $K$ such that if $k>K$ then $|\sum_{n=1}^k A(n)-a|<\frac\delta2$ and there is $J$ such that if $j>J$ then $|\sum_{n=1}^j B(n)-b|<\frac\delta2$. Just to get you started. Make a sincere effort, figure the rest of it :)

Comment: Can you write a full proof or even a sketch please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm referring to the notation in the link where the mash-up of two sequences is defined.

Let an $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then Cauchy's criterion for series  guarantees the following: There is an $N$ with
$$\left|\sum_{j=r+1}^{r+p} a_j\right|<\epsilon,\qquad \left|\sum_{k=r+1}^{r+p} b_k\right|<\epsilon\qquad(r\geq N, \ p\geq1)\ .\tag{1}$$  Put $N':=n_N+m_N$. In the finite sequence $(c_1,c_2,c_3,\ldots, c_{N'})$ we see $a_1$, $\ldots$, $a_{n_N}$ and $b_1$, $\ldots$, $b_{m_N}$ interweaved. Therefore a sum of the form
$$\sum_{l=r+1}^{r+p} c_l\qquad(r\geq N')$$  contains only succesive $a_j$'s and $b_k$'s with
$$j>n_N\geq N,\qquad k>m_N\geq N\ ,$$
and it follows from $(1)$ that
$$\left|\sum_{l=r}^{r+p} c_l\right|<2\epsilon\qquad(r>M, \ p\geq1)\ .$$
This proves that the series $\sum_{l=1}^\infty c_l$ satisfies the Cauchy criterion for series, hence is convergent.

Since one has
$$\sum_{l\leq n_i+m_i} c_l=\sum_{j\leq n_i} a_j+\sum_{k\leq m_i} b_k\qquad(i\geq1)$$
we can conclude that in fact
$$\sum_l c_l=\sum_j a_j+\sum_k b_k\  .$$